# Does Ubuntu V12.04.2 work on a system that normally run Windows 7 64bit with an Intel processor?

Tags: installation

Can't get ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386. I get the message "No DEFAULT or UI directive found! boot:" After the failure on the WIN7 machine I took the exact same CD and used it on an older WIN XP 32 bit machine. The disk worked prefectly on the 32 bit machine.